# How to create folders for the consumers of a gem, when they run bundle install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am new to creating gems with ruby. I want to create some folders when consumers run `bundle install` for my gem. I've tried so far to do this in the `bin/setup` file that comes with the creation of a gem with https://bundler.io/man/bundle-gem.1.html

```
echo "test"
mkdir test
```

I expect to see the log and the folder when I install my gem in an app, and run bundle install, but nothing happens.

Could someone point me into the right direction? Where should I place these initializers?

I checked the `devise gem`, they use this generators concept https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/tree/main/lib/generators

But this is from Rails https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html, I would like to do it without the rails gem

Comment: I suggest asking/configuring the user what folder they want to use.

Comment: What i want is to create them, like devise that you have some already. I just want to do mkdir

Comment: What I basically need is, whenever the user do gem 'my-gem' in Gemfile, and runs bundle install, that some folders are created.